# Could not save as .ACCDE file (Could not use <file>; file already in use)

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to save ACCDB file as ACCDE but I got **"Could not use [file path]; file already in use"** error no matter how many times i tried.. i got 2 tables, 1 forms and 3 reports. Using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019

Comment: Have you tried a reboot? Probably there is a rogue process locking the file.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I tried reboot and restarted the Access and my computer but it doesnt work as well.. btw i closed every forms reports and tables when i try to save